# abcpdf gecko not rendering images

Tags: asp-classic, abcpdf

I'm attempting to make a PDF from a HTML document, and this document has images absolutely linked (ie. C:/somewhere/html.htm), but when I use abcpdf 8.1 `AddImageUrl("file:\\"&absLocation,True,0,False)` the resulting pdf doesn't have any images.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the images to show up?

Side info: when using vbscript and default mshtml as the engine, it all gets saved to pdf perfectly, but in asp it didn't save at all using mshtml. Thus the switch to Gecko.

I'm using this on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit machine with IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I had to prepend `file://` to my image references within the html as well.

So IMG elements should look like this:

```
<img src="file://c:\directorys\image.png" alt="There should be an image here />
```